# Problems rooting Samsung Galaxy S: SuperOneClick stops responding at step 7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rooting

I am having an awful time trying to update my new Galaxy S to ICS. I found a well rated ROM .zip on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/ice-cream-sandwich-sgs/) but first I need to root the phone so I can unlock the bootloader. I have been googling all week and read lots of posts saying SuperOneClick is the way to go, but it keeps freezing. It gets to step 7 and stops. There are many threads out there where people say they have the same problem as me, but there is no answer to these posts, or the response is 'well it worked for me', which isn't much help. I also thought of giving Odin a go, but I do not believe my ROM is compatable (doesn't have PDA, CSC etc. elements to select). There must be something I'm missing or the tutorials I've read have left out. Or something else stopping SuperOneClick from finishing it's task.

I get no error messages during the rooting process. SuperOneClick just plain stops responding.

- Samsung Galaxy S i9000
- Android Gingerbread 2.3.6
- Bootloader 3e
- ROM ICS_4.0.3_MR1-RC4.2_I9000.zip from code.google.com (http://code.google.com/p/ice-cream-sandwich-sgs/)
- SuperOneClick version 2.3.3

Comment: I'd suggest CM9 which went stable yesterday: [howto](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide) install is here. You're sure you have the exact i9000 model and not the i9001? CM9 is here: [get.cm](http://get.cm/?device=galaxysmtd&type=stable). CyanogenMod is imho the most popular and renowned Android aftermarket firmware

Comment: Reading the How To, it looks quite self explanatory. However, I still need to root the phone first. And it definitely is the i9000, I just don't know which name it has (Captivate, Fascinate, Vibrant etc.) I am in Australia if that narrows it down.

Comment: You need root in case you want to backup everything using TitaniumBackup. The real steps are installing CWM and then Cyanogenmod. Seems like you have the 'galaxysmtd' model btw.

Comment: Downloaded CyanogenMod and attempted to flash. I got the same result as I did for the other ROM I tried - I get an 'E:signature verification failed' error. According to my googling, this is to do with the 3e bootloader not accepting the digital signature of the update and rejecting the process. The fix suggested is to root the current system, use a ROM manager to remove the signature checking option for the bootloader, then flash the ROM.

Comment: Scratch that last comment. I missed a step in the use of Heimdall which replaces the bootloader. I shall now attempt my ROM install

Comment: I have now managed to flash with the CyanogenMod ROM and now have ICS in all it's glory. Many thanks [ce4](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/15713/ce4)

Comment: Ah, nice! That'd been my next question. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recomended by CE4 above, I just followed the steps laid out in this tutorial.

[Samsung Galaxy S: Full Update Guide](http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S%3a_Full_Update_Guide)

You can download the ROM from get.cm [here](http://get.cm/?device=galaxysmtd) (original Samsung Galaxy S variant) or [here](http://get.cm/?device=galaxysbmtd) (Samsung Galaxy S (B) variant), note these are only for i9000 (not i9001 or i9003).